# How to increase node.js request timeout when deployed to dedicated bluemix environment

Tags: node.js, timeout, ibm-cloud, response, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating an application that run long request, node.js server has a restriction and times out after 2 minutes. I tried these solutions and all worked fine when running local, but failed when the application is deployed to bluemix

```
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity
server.setTimeout(0)
res.setTimeout(0)
req.setTimeout(0)
```

I don't know what else to try. any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that bluemix is using some sort of proxy or load balancer in front of your web server and that's where the timeout is occurring.  You will have to research their infrastructure settings to see if you can control that. Also, you might be able to keep the intervening infrastructure from timing out if you occasionally do a `res.write()` of something small from the server, though you will have to make sure that isn't buffered and is actually sent right away.

Comment: And, here's a module that might be of use: [http delayed response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-delayed-response).  It will send a single space character every so often to keep the connection alive for long polling applications.